# float left wrapping parent instead of nested divs

Tags: css

trying to build responsive layout from scratch after hours of not getting it just right with bootstrap. My goal is to have fixed width tiles wrap under each other as the display is resized, but not wrap under a sidebar div if there is still enough width in a div to the right of the sidebar to show them.

With the following bare example, I expect the tiles to wrap under each other and under the "filters and search" div, but not under the "content" div on the far left until the width of the display is very narrow. As the width starts to decrease, everything to the right of the sidebar div appears below it, even though there is plenty of space on the right to start stacking. Any suggestions?

```
Here is the code (no stylesheets to show everything here:)

<div style="border:1px solid red;width:200px;float:left;" id="sidebar">
    <div>content1</div>
    <div>content2</div>
    <div>content3</div>
    <div>content4</div>
    <div>content5</div>
    <div>content6</div>
</div>
<div style="border:1px yellow solid;float:left;" id="contentarea">
    <div style="border:1px solid;float:left;">filters and search</div>
          <div style="border:1px solid;clear:left;">
          <div style="border:1px solid blue;float:left;width:200px;margin-right:20px;">tile 1</div>
          <div style="border:1px solid blue;float:left;width:200px;margin-right:20px;">tile 2</div>
          <div style="border:1px solid blue;float:left;width:200px;margin-right:20px;">tile 3</div>

      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: here is a fiddle. if you resize the result pane, you can see them on the right of the sidebar, and then make it narrow and the tiles appear under it, instead of stacking under themselves on the right of the sidebar.
http://jsfiddle.net/phatair/pRthu/

Answer (score 0):

try using css for screen size example:
@ media only screen and (min-width: 1550px) {}
@ media only screen and (max-width: 1449px) {}